# Get image from relative path

Tags: java

In my project I have 2 packages.
**images** - contain images and 
**notification** - contain java files

In notification/main.java I get Image object from  image using this code

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("/images/key-16x16.png");
```

and I can't get image.

How can I fix this bug.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm using Netbeans to develop Java desktop application and I have solved my problem.

```
Image image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/bell-icon16.png")).getImage();
```

"this" is a class **extends** JFrame

Comment: ImageIcon().getImage() is a good solution! works for me as well here using windows 64bit. :D

Answer (score 7):

`/` means an absolute path, save Java web-apps where `/` means relative to context. So, I would suggest to use relative URL, means get rid of that `/` in front, and then provide the right path.

In case, even then you can't solve it, try to create a file on the same path you are looking for image. This way you will know that where you are looking exactly and where you should look.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try

```
Image image = new ImageIcon(path).getImage();
```

Answer (score 2):

Incase the solution above doesn't work, try this (which worked for me):

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(this.getClass().getResource("/Images/bell-icon16.png"));
```

Answer (score 1):

i've also been on this and it turns out that you need to create a package inside of your src folder.
for instace if you  create a package called images inside of the src folder, your relative path will be
/images/yourimage.png.

Notice that the slash(/) must be there!
more info here http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=533922

it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Class<? extends JFrame> j = YOURJFRAME.getClass();
Image image = tk.createImage(j.getResource("/images/bell-icon16.png"));
```

Try that code, if you have a JFrame that will work. 
If you have an Applet, then just use

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Image image = tk.createImage("images/bell-icon16.png");
```

With applets you never want to use the / in the beginning, but if you have a JFrame, and you are using getResource, you need the / in the beginning of the Path.

Comment: for this one, i tried inside netbeans it works. But once i pack the app into an external package installer, seems the referencing doesnt work properly. :( dont know why.

Comment: @gumuruh what app installer? I might not be able to help, but what it does probably does change what you need to do.

Comment: nevermind 'DaboRoss, coz I already follow the @ChanPye solutions above and it works. :D

app installer what i wrote last time is Advanced Installer. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
SwingResourceManager.getImage(YourClass.class,"key-16x16.png");
```

The `getIcon` method will return Icon as similar

Answer (score 0):

```java
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("../resources/MainIcon.png")));
```