# What is the correct path for Toolkit.getImage()?

Tags: java, awt

I need to upload an image file and generate a thumbnail for the uploaded file in my JSF webapplication. The original image is stored on the server in `/home/myname/tomcat/webapps/uploads`, while the thumbnail is stored in `/home/myname/tomcat/webapps/uploads/thumbs`. I'm using the thumbnail generator class I copied from [philreeve.com](http://www.philreeve.com/java_high_quality_thumbnails.php).

I have successfully uploaded the file with help from [BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/02/uploading-files-with-jsf.html). But using `Toolkit.getImage()`, I can't access the image.

I used the uploaded file's absolute path, like so:

```
inFilename = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

The relevant code from the thumbnail generator is:

```
public static String createThumbnail(String inFilename, String outFilename, int largestDimension) {
    ...
    Image inImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(inFilename);
    if (inImage.getWidth(null) == -1 || inImage.getHeight(null) == -1) {
        return "Error loading file: \"" + new File(inFilename).getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
    }
    ...
}
```

Since I am already using the absolute path, I don't understand why it is not working. I have also used the following values for `inFilename`, but I always get the "Error loading file...".

- `/home/myname/tomcat/webapps/uploads/filename.ext`
- `/uploads/filename.ext`

But I did check the directory, and the image *is* there. (I uploaded using `/home/myname/tomcat/webapps/uploads/filename.ext`, and it works.) What is the correct path for the image in that directory? Thank you.

**Update**

I got the code to work by using:

```
Image inImage = ImageIO.read(new File(inFilename));
```

I still don't understand why `Toolkit.getImage()` does not work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's a JPEG file? Use an image viewer to make sure nothing bad happened to the file during upload (or that it was an image to begin with).

Also, use `new File(inFilename).exists()` to make sure the path is correct. I also suggest to print `new File(inFilename).getAbsolutePath()` in error messages because relative paths can hurt you.

That said, the rest of the code looks correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The `.jpg` was just an example, sorry for the misunderstanding. I'm actually getting the file's suffix. I tried viewing the image in the browser: `http://***:8082/uploads/filename.jpg`, and it displays correctly. I changed the code, thanks for that. I'll continue to work on the problem, but I have a feeling that `getAbsolutePath()` will come in handy. :)

Comment: Hello, I have updated my code and the original post. Now I am sure the file exists because I am using the absolute path of the just-successfully-uploaded file. But even that does not work. If you have any ideas, I would appreciate hearing them. Thanks. :)

Comment: I just used `ImageIO.read()` instead of `Tookit.getImage()`, and it works. Thanks for the absolute path suggestion, I honestly could not have thought of it myself with my rusty Java skills. It would have been ugly to hardcode the location. Thanks for the time. :)

Comment: Suggestion: Write a simple test case which just loads the image from a file and displays it to make sure nothing else interferes. If that works, expand the test. If it doesn't work, post the code here in a  new question so maybe someone can find the problem.

Comment: Start with this code: http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/graphics2D/display-image-using-toolkit.shtml

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Seeing that I use the exact same file for `ImageIO.read()` and `Toolkit.getImage()`, my (wild) guess is that `Toolkit.getImage()` works only for applet types? :/

Comment: No, `Toolkit` is for the desktop UI. Swing uses it all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Toolkit.getImage()` does not return the image immediately. The issue is well-described in [this bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4298019), a relevant extract of which is here:

> This is not a bug. The submitter is not properly using the asynchronous
> Image API correctly. He assumes that getImage loads all of the image's bits
> into memory. However, it is well documented that the actual loading of
> bits does not take place until a call to Component.prepareImage or
> Graphics.drawImage. In addition, these two functions return *before* the
> Image is fully loaded. Developers are required to install an ImageObserver
> to listen for notification that the Image has been fully loaded. Once they
> receive this notification, they can repaint the Image.

I found that the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978445/get-image-from-relative-path) works well:

`Image image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/bell-icon16.png")).getImage();`